# Product of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Pair of numbers whose product is $+7$ and whose sum is $-8$. 
Factorise $x^{2} - 8x + 7$.

I can factorise but it's just I can't find any products of $+7$ and that is a sum of 
$-8$. Any idea? Thanks guys!

Thanks.

Comment: Please help, thanks.

Comment: oh damn, wrong numbers/ I meant +7 and -8.

Comment: please make it simple, lol I'm only a teengaer with raging hormones and a weird brain

Comment: sorry lol wrote the question aboslutely wrong

Comment: @user61406: something is wrong with the signs in your question, it should be $+8x$. Please see my answer. Did you make a sign error? Regards

Comment: ok thanks for answering, it's -8 though i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x y = 7$

$x + y = -8$

$y = \frac{7}{x}$, so

$x + \frac{7}{x} = -8$

Multiplying by $x$, yields:

$$x^2 +8x +7 = 0$$

$$(x+1)(x+7) = 0$$

Can you take it from there?

Regards

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!!!!!!!!!!!! LOL I only get your explanation!

Comment: @user61406: you are very welcome! It helps to acknowledge people who answered questions by upvoting them and there are some nice answers. You should also accept the answer you like best. Regards

Comment: damn, well I think I got your the best. Other answers were sqaure roots and inspections etc... Smart people lol

Comment: What wonderful feedback! Your answer deserves more $\uparrow$'s $\quad +1$

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the easiest approach is easiest! Simplicity works! :-)

Comment: How did you factor $x^2+8x+7$?

Comment: Since $7$ is prime, its only factors are $1, 7$ and I need an $8$ as a sum, thus $(x+1)(x+7)$. Clear? Regards

Answer (score 4):

If you can factorize $x^2 - 8x + 7$, then you can solve a quadratic equation.

Now recall that if the roots of $x^2+bx+c=0$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $-b = \alpha + \beta$ and $c = \alpha \beta$.

(This is because $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = x^2 - (\alpha+\beta) x + \alpha \beta$.)

Comment: lol thanks, I know I was just a big confused I guess!

Answer (score 0):

$(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$

So, you are looking for the roots of $x^2-(+2)x+(-3)$, that is, $x^2-2x-3$, which is $=x^2-2x+1-4=(x-1)^2-4$, and this is $0$ iff $(x-1)^2=4$, that is, $x-1=\pm 2$, i.e., $-1,3$ is your solution.

Similarly for the other one: $x^2-8x+7=(x-4)^2-16+7=\dots$

Or, the other way: $7+1=8$ and $7\cdot 1=7$, so the roots of $x^2-8x+7$ are $1$ and $7$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you are trying to factorise $x^2-8x+7$. I suggest you use viete's formulae. xy=2 and x+y=-3. Let's say you have a quadratic equation $x^2+ax+b$ Then the roots $x_1, x_2$ has the property $x_1+x_2=-a$ and $x_1.x_2=c$ So you have the quadratic equation $x^2-2x-3$ When you solve this, you get the answer.

Comment: solve it? lol what do you mean? like factorise that? sos

Comment: yeah sorry :D I meant to solve the equation $x^2-2x-3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

> your questions answer are already users have given so i'm not repeating them.
>   sometimes factorization is not easy because number are too big to manually calculate or may be fractional so try this formula as alternative.
>   roots for equation $(ax^2+bx-c)=0$ is,
>   $x=\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4\cdot a\cdot c}}{2\cdot a}$ , 
>   $\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4\cdot a\cdot c}}{2\cdot a}$